# Space issue in Linux Mint 19.1

Tags: linux-mint, disk-space

I couldn't enter into my Linux Mint system using the correct password. After deleting `/var/cache/`, I could enter into my system.

I can't save and download any files now.

Maybe I am going to face this situation again.

What is the solution?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you have deleted `/var/cache`, then recreate it with `sudo mkdir /var/cache` then re-login and try again. If you are running out of space, then you need to find out what is using it. Try `du -sH /*`, then iterate through the directories and check within them.

Answer (score 1):

The messages seem pretty clear:

```
No space left on device.
```

and

```
There is not enough room on the disk to save.
```

You are out of disk space. You need a larger disk or remove data.

You can see how much room you have left with `df`.

When you deleted `/var/cache`, you freed-up some disk space. That's when you could log in again. So, either delete some files, or add some disk space, otherwise you won't be able to use your system again.

It may be, that there is some runaway process that creates enormous files. You will have to find out what  file that is. In general, use `du -sk * | sort -n` in the top directory, and go down in the largest sub-dir. In general, those extremely large files will be somewhere under `/tmp`, `/var` or `/home`, but ymmv.

Comment: Thanks @Ljm . But what is the solution ?

Comment: As I said, "You need a larger disk or remove data."